# The sum of the $n^{\text{th}}$ powers of the roots of a monic polynomial with integer coefficents is always integer

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, induction

The following question is inspired by

[Proving that the sum of $n^{th}$ powers of the roots of a quadratic with integer coefficients is also an integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4226547/proving-that-the-sum-of-nth-powers-of-the-roots-of-a-quadratic-with-integer/4226553#4226553)

I am curious, if we can generalize it to all monic polynomials with integer coefficents, i.e. is the sum of the $n^{\text{th}}$ powers of the roots of a monic polynomial with integer coefficents always integer?

Here is what i have done so far:

Let $p(x)=x^d+\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}c_i\cdot x^i$ with $c_i\in \mathbb Z$. Let $\alpha$ be an arbitrary root of $p$, then from $\alpha^n+\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}c_i\cdot\alpha^i=0$ follows
$$
\alpha^{d}=-\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}c_i\cdot\alpha^i
$$
Hence, for $n\geq d$, we can multiply by $\alpha^{n-d}$ and get
$$
\alpha^{n}=-\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}c_i\cdot\alpha^{n-d+i}.
$$
Since this holds for all roots, we can sum up this equation over all roots of $p$ but with a fixed $n$. Let $s_n$ be the sum of the $n^{\text{th}}$ power of all roots of $p$, we get for $n\geq d$
$$
s_n = -\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}c_i\cdot s_{n-d+i},
$$
which is an integer, if $s_0, \ldots, s_{d-1}$ are integers. And here I stuck, because I can't prove, that they are integers. I know, that $s_0=d$ and $s_1=(-1)^{d+1}c_1$ are integers, but nothing more.

Comment: Note that the polynomial must be assumed to be **monic** otherwise the result is obviously false for a degree one polynomial which is not monic.

Comment: Yes, thank you :) That's correct. This is, where is induction base fails. I will correct it.

Comment: The polynomial $\,qx+p\,$ has one root $\,x=-p/q.\,$ The polynomial $\,qx^2+px\,$ has two roots $\,x=-p/q,0.\,$ The sum of the $n$-th power of the roots of each polynomial is the same as for the other for $\,n>0.$

Comment: Yes, you're right, i already saw it. But thank you :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Let $Q=X_1^n + ... + X_d^n \in \mathbb{Z}[X_1,...,X_d]$. The polynomial $Q$ is a symmetric polynomial, so by the [fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials), $Q$ is a polynomial in the elementary symmetric polynomials $e_1, ..., e_d$. So if $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_d$ denote the roots of $p$, you get that $Q(\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_d)$ is a polynomial (with integer coefficients) in the $e_k(\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_d)$, which are exactly the *coefficients* of $p$. So $Q(\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_d)$ is a polynomial  in the coefficients of $p$, and because $p$ has integer coefficients, then $Q(\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_d) \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Notice that this works for any symmetric polynomial instead of $Q$.

Comment: I like this answer. Why does somebody vote it down?

Comment: @Jochen I am asking myself the same question :)

Comment: Should i delete the question? It's not that trivial.

Comment: @Jochen No, I think this is a good question ! (I don't know either why your question has been downvoted too...)

Comment: Thank you very much :)